# Write a function in C++ in which the client decides what function to run from the class?

Tags: c++

I've been wondering if it's possible for the client / user to decide what function to run from the class.

For example, Say I have the following function:

```
std::vector<double> greeks_mesh_pricer(const Greeks& Greek, (function to Run), int mesh_size) {
    std::vector<double> result;
    for(int i = 0; i < mesh_size; i += mesh_size) {
        result.push_back(Greek.(function to run));
    }
}
```

Function to run, is a member function of the Greek class. Greeks here is an interface containing pure virtual functions, so the user is actually passing
in a Derived class of Greeks. So if the client specifies the function Delta(), it returns a vector of Delta() results, etc.

Comment: I'm confused. is `mesh_size` supposed to be input for the specified function, or is it supposed to be a count of how many times to run it? If it's a count, why are you using a `double`, and why are you running the function the same way each time?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Everything is possible in C++. This is what an "if" statement is for. `if (command == "geeks_mesh_pricer") geeks_mesh_pricer(arguments...)`. Repeat for every function.

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused. is `Delta` really one of the member functions named in the `Greek` interface, or is it a derived class? It makes more sense to me as the latter, since "delta" *is* a "greek" (letter). (I assume the code has something to do with the pricing of stock options.)

Comment: You could also use a map to map some input value to a std::function

Comment: pointer on member is a possibility.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You are correct. This is a class for computing Greeks for stock options. Delta() is a pure virtual function in Greeks and implemented by EuropeanCallOptionGreeks.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, this seems tailor made for pointer-to-member-function. But I might have misunderstood the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with pointers to member functions:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
    virtual void bar() const = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
    void foo() const { std::cout << "Derived1::foo\n"; }
    void bar() const { std::cout << "Derived1::bar\n"; }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
    void foo() const { std::cout << "Derived2::foo\n"; }
    void bar() const { std::cout << "Derived2::bar\n"; }
};

void invoke(const Base &b, void (Base::*func)() const) {
    (b.*func)();
}

int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;

    invoke(d1, &Base::foo);
    invoke(d2, &Base::foo);
    invoke(d1, &Base::bar);
    invoke(d2, &Base::bar);
}
```

Output

```
Derived1::foo
Derived2::foo
Derived1::bar
Derived2::bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows has implemented that sort of automation with [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch), you can implement a similar one if not using Windows. The idea is to specify a function by ID (or translated from a name) and to pass the arguments as VARIANTs.

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking about function pointers in C++. Just like a pointer can be use to reference a variable or object, similarly pointers can be used to reference a function as well and you can also pass a function to a function using these pointers or create an array of pointers where each pointer is actually a function pointer (reference to a function).

Read here : https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to represent and store a function. You can also use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [`std::placeholder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) to facilitate the whole thing. Example:

```
struct A {
  int f(int);
  int g(int);
};

A instance;
std::function<int(int)> client_fn;
using namespace std::placeholders;
if (...) {
    client_fn = std::bind(&A::f, &instance, _1);
} else {
    client_fn = std::bind(&A::g, &instance, _1);
}
```